# awscli -- getting certain prefix of objects (or, folder-equivalant) for S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a bucket which has several folders (I'm just going to call them folders for easier understanding. I know folders don't really exist in S3), so the structure looks like this

```
my_bucket
 |
 |- 2018-11-06-01
      |- file_name1
      |- file_name2
 |- 2018-11-06-02
      |- file_name1
      |- file_name2
```

I'm trying to only get the latest files, those in the latest folder

I can get the folder name string by doing `aws s3 ls my_bucket/ | tail -1` but it'll return `PRE 2018-11-06-02/`

How do I get the folder name by processing the string so that I can perform `aws s3 cp my_bucket/2018-11-06-02/ <some_path> --recursive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to write as a one-liner solution, something like this could do the trick:

```
aws s3 ls <bucket> \
    | sort \
    | tail -n 1 \
    | awk '{print $2}' \
    | xargs -I {} aws s3 cp <bucket>/{} <local_folder> --recursive
```

you can read the one-liner as 2 parts:
- first it reads the ls with sorting and taking the 2nd value of the output (taking out the `PRE` part of the bucket name) 
- second you pass the results (the "folder" name) that you can use to copy fiels from the bucket locally.

Comment: I tried replacing <bucket> with my bucket_name and local_folder with the the folder I wanna copy to, yet I'm getting `usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri> Error: Invalid argument type`, should I do something with the brackets?

Comment: okay my bad. Apparently I need `s3://` in front of bucket name

Comment: you're correct `aws s3` works with `s3://` in front while `s3api` takes the bucket name only

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last modified filename (including full path) with:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

You could then extract the path up to the final `/` using shell tools and send it to a copy command.

Alternatively, code it up in Python (or another preferred language).

Comment: yea I was looking for some quick shell one-line solution. Otherwise I'd just do it in python. Thanks for your answer though